# get name from id inside loop in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hello all I am new to node js and mongo db so I am facing a problem which is written above want to match an id  from an array and get all the record of matching id , but thats not working i have already tried for loop but that is taking too much time so i am looking for some kind of query by which I pass id and get the matching results i have below function also where i can pass id and get the matching result but i don't know how to call that .

```
exports.getDistrictFromId = function(req, res, next) {
  var distId = req.params.id;
  districtslib.getDistricts({_id: utils.toObjectId(distId)}, function(err, district) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.store.district = district;
    next();
  });
};
```

Here is my code

```
    exports.getCompleteTeachersList = function(req, res, next) {

      var query = req.store.get('query');
      var teacherQuery = {enabled: true};
      var searchQuery = '';
      if (!_.isUndefined(query)) {

          //      schoolQuery = {'name':new RegExp(query.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"),'i')};
          //{ $text: { $search: "amit hinduja"} }
          //teacherQuery = {enabled: true,$or:[{firstName:new RegExp(query.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"),'i')},{lastName:new RegExp(query.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"),'i')}]};
          if(query.trim() != '') {
            teacherQuery = {enabled: true,$text: { $search: query} };
            searchQuery = query;
          }
      }

      teacherslib.getTeachers(teacherQuery, function(err, teachers) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        var schools  = req.store.get('schools');
        for(var i = 0; i < teachers.length; i++) {
        teachers[i].schoolName    = "";
            for(var j = 0; j < schools.length; j++) {
                if (teachers[i].schoolId.toString() === schools[j]._id.toString()) {
                    teachers[i].schoolName  = schools[j].name; 
                    teachers[i].distId      = "";
                    var districts           = req.store.get('districts');
                    console.log(schools[j].distId);
// i want to get the array of matching district id `schools[j].distId` from the district array from `var districts = req.store.get('districts');` this line
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
        req.store.set('searchQuery', searchQuery);
        req.store.set('teachers', teachers);
        //req.store.set('districts', districts);

        next();
      });
    };
```

Collection structure is like this 
1) distid is coming in schools collection
using distid get all the matching record from district
2)district array has countyid and from that county id has to get data from the county collection

Comment: What is your collection structure?

Comment: @hyades just updated the question please review

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping inside a loop, i would suggest you look into the [$lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) of the aggregation framework. Here you can perform the lookup server side.

Comment: is there a way where we can get multiple collections data in a single query like mysql do ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? You can add as many lookup stages as you want.